# Create a macro that automatically updates time & date but doesn't change when I type in other cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

At my job we have this CSR sheet that we use for self service. 
The idea is you fill each row as a call is taken every day
and then email it to our boss. 
I put an example of the sheet at the bottom.

However the issue I'm having is that we fill these rows in really fast
(every minute or so)
and for me and the other users to keep typing the time and date
feels redundant (since the date value is, of course, the same all day long).

So I tried using the `Now()` worksheet function, but the time is dynamic,
so every time I start a new line ALL the times update. 
I tried reading about VBA here, but I just don't understand.

My question is:  How can I have this spreadsheet input the date & time and have it be static in columns C & D, when I put data in columns E, F & G? 
So we don't have to manually enter it ourselves?

This is the example:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Agent Name | Supervisor | ***Date*** | ***Time*** | Did you collect callback? | Did you HIPPA verify? | Did you offer self service? |  |
| 2 | Alex | Rebecca | ***12/14/2022*** | ***4:34 PM*** | Yes | yes | yes |  |
| ︙ | ︙ | ︙ |  |  |  |  |  |  |

<sup>[transcribed from [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3kjl.png)]</sup>

I'm trying to find a way to optimize the process as much as I can! 
Manual entry of the date and time
causes production to slow down and mistakes to be made. 
Many of the users are not high education or elderly
and might have trouble with techniques like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+**<kbd>;</kbd>**
and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+**<kbd>;</kbd>**.

Comment: Based on you saying that you don't understand VBA, then I would say the easiest is to start with the `now()` formula, AND as you fill in each row use copy/paste value to convert the formula to a value that won't change. Beyond this it sounds like your company needs to invest in CSR application rather than using excel...

Comment: I just noticed, while editing your question, that you say “have this spreadsheet input the date & time … in columns C & D, when I put data in columns E, F & G”.  Why that wording?  Do you want nothing to happen when columns `A` and `B` are filled in?  Are you handling them in bulk?

Comment: Related: [Show a timestamp when a cell is changed](https://superuser.com/q/886385/150988).

Answer (score 0):

No offense, but: how lazy are you? 
If you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+**<kbd>;</kbd>** (in Column C),
Excel will insert the current date *as a static value.* 
Type <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or **<kbd>→</kbd>**) (to move to Column D),
then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+**<kbd>;</kbd>** to insert the current time.

Reference: [Insert the current date and time in a cell (Microsoft Support)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-the-current-date-and-time-in-a-cell-b5663451-10b0-40ab-9e71-6b0ce5768138)

Comment: Very! But I work with a lot of individuals who are not high education or elderly or simply just needed a job. And as common as that information might be most of them do not know this or wouldn't care to use it. This causes production to slow down and mistakes to be made. I'm trying to find a way to optimize that as much as I can! Sure its easy to push a button but why do it if you don't have to?. But if you don't have an answer that works too, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create this VBA routine:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Static recursive As Integer
    Dim cur_row As Integer
    Dim cur_time
    Const date_col As Integer = 3
    Const time_col As Integer = 4

    cur_row = Target.Row
    If recursive = 0 And Cells(cur_row, date_col) = "" And Cells(cur_row, time_col) = "" Then
        recursive = 1
        cur_time = Now()
        Cells(cur_row, date_col) = Int(cur_time)
        Cells(cur_row, time_col) = cur_time - Int(cur_time)
        Cells(cur_row, date_col).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        Cells(cur_row, time_col).NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
        recursive = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

It will be called every time any cell is changed.

- The assignment statements in the `Worksheet_Change` routine
  change the worksheet and therefore trigger recursive calls to the routine. 
  We use the `recursive` variable to detect this
  and prevent recursive execution.
- Declare variables for the current row and the current date/time.
- Declare integer constants to designate the Date column (`C`)
  and the Time column (`D`).
- Set `cur_row` to the row containing the cell that was changed.
- If it’s not a recursive call,
  and the date and time in the current row are blank, then
- Get the current date/time (an Excel date/time value,
  which is an integer date plus a fraction of a day).
- Set the Date cell (in the current row) to today’s date
  (the integer part of `cur_time`).
- Set the Time column to the fractional residue
  (the time; 0 = midnight, 0.25 = 6 AM, 0.5 = noon, 0.75 = 6 PM, etc.) 
  Once these values are entered, they are static.
- Set the formats of the cells.

Note that this will take action in a row
only the first time the row is modified
(unless the user clears the `C` and `D` columns). 
If the user changes cells in multiple rows simultaneously,
only the first one will be processed.

You might want to consider hiding columns `C` and `D`,
so the users aren’t confused by them,
and don’t need to explicitly skip over them.

[How do I add VBA in MS Office?](/q/801609/150988) is a useful reference
for getting started on the mechanics of working with VBA.